# Is my writing original if it is a hybrid of Tolkien and Rowling?

Tags: fiction, publishing, fantasy, copyright, originality

I am planning to write a fantasy book which incorporates the styles of LotR and Harry Potter.

The setting is a Middle Earth-like world. The main character attends a magical school.
There is a substance like Elixir from Clash of Clans. 
The world exists hidden in Antarctica. The beginning of the story is similar to that of the Wizard of Oz.

Is my writing original? 
Your comments are more precious than diamonds to me. 
Thank you.

Comment: Many previous questions on this topic: [tag:originality]

Comment: it may be a good idea to search the site for mentions of fan fictions and how to avoid your story becoming fan fiction, one such question that may be helpful is [here](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/31599/32186)

Answer (score 0):

Creative work builds on what has come before it; *it's not so much the elements of the story that matter, as how you put them together*. One plot line can be written in so many different ways, and still be published (basically all the YA fiction out there). In the end, it's your writing, not theirs, and that by default makes it original.